# "If == null" equivalent in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want do model a knowledge base where I can assert expenses on different online shops as facts. One rule should now be able to calculate the sum of these expenses. The clue is that I have different discounts on the shops. My facts:

```
expense(shopA, 450).
expense(shopB, 60).
```

My rule:

```
sumOfExpenses(X):-
   expense(shopA, A),
   expense(shopB, B),
   expense(shopC, C),
   X is A*0.05 + B*0.25 + C*0.1.
```

The execution of sumOfExpenses(X) returns false. I did some debugging and if I would add for example: `expense(shopC, 50).` to the facts it would work.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an additional set of facts to represent the shop discounts. E.g.

```
discount(shopA, 0.05).
discount(shopB, 0.55).
discount(shopC, 0.10).
```

This is a more readable, maintainable, and scalable solution than hard-wiring the discounts in the sum of expenses formula. It also allows you to write a more flexible version of the `sum_of_expenses/1` predicate. E.g.

```
sum_of_expenses(Sum) :-
    findall(
       Value,
       (   expense(Shop, Expense),
           discount(Shop, Discount),
           Value is Expense * Discount
       ),
       Values
    ),
    sum(Values, Sum).
```

Only the shops for which there is an expense will be used in the computation. I will leave to you writing the `sum/2` predicate as an exercise.